# Unable to run my code in Ipython notebook.

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am unable to run my code inside the Ipython notebook. Whenever I run my code, the notebook gets struck and it displays the processing symbol(*).  But when I close my notebook and open it again and then execute my command, I am able to run my commands inside the notebook. Can you please help me with this

```
In [*]: print "data"
```

After closing and reopening the notebook

```
In [2]:print "data"
  data
```

Comment: At the end of the day, it works, doesn't it ? What's the problem otherwise ?

Comment: @jeanrjc - It works, but sometimes it is getting struck. I am using enthought canopy, does installing anaconda, solve this problem??

Comment: It seems that the notebook has been shut down. If you're on unix you can try in command line, and see in the terminal what happens when it get stuck.

Comment: @jeanrjc -I am using windows. I am not using windows. I going to resnitalling canopy. Hope it fixes the issue. Thanks a lot for the help !!!